# Trying to get property of non-object in simple php MVC code

Tags: php, model-view-controller

This questions has been answered many time, but am unable to find proper solution here.

Am new to php MVC framework.am trying to execute a code that is available online. here the html page displays fine with combobox for selection, but when i select an item and submit am getting this error. can anyone help me in understanding the problem and solve it.

Here is the code

Book class:

```php
class Book
{
    public $name;
    public $version;
    public $yop;

    public function __construct($name, $version, $yop)
    {
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> version = $version;
        $this->yop=$yop;
    }
}
```

Model class :

```php
class Model
{
    public $text;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->text="Book selection";
    }

    public function getBookList()
    {
        return array(
            'PHP for Absolute Beginners' => new Book ('PHP for Absolute Beginners', '1.2', '1999'),
            'Basic Introduction to PHP MVC' => new Book ('Basic Introduction to PHP MVC', '1.0', '2008'),
            'Advanced PHP' => new Book ('Advanced PHP', '1.2', '2004'),
            'Advanced PHP MVC' => new Book ('Advanced PHP MVC', '2.0', '2014')
        );
    }

    public function getBook($name)
    {
        $allBooks= $this->getBookList();

        return $allBooks;
    }
}
```

controller class:

```php
class Controller
{
    public $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model=$model;
    }

    public function invoke()
    {
        if (!isset($_GET['book'])) {
            return $this->model->getBookList();

        } else {
            return '<h2>'.$this->model ->text.'</h2>';
        }
    }

    public function output()
    {
        return'<h1>' . $this -> model -> text . '</h1>';
    }
}
```

finally this is the view

```php
$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);

echo $controller-> output();

$books = $controller ->invoke();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET") {

    if (isset($_GET['book'])) {
        echo "You selected " . $books->name . " version: " . $books->version . " Year of published: " . $books->yop;

        exit();
    }
}
```

this is the HTML form for submitting data

```html
<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="book">
        <?php
            foreach ($books as $x=>$x_value) {
                echo '<option value="' . $x . '">' . $x . '</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select" name="submit">
</form>
```

any suggestion please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If isset GET variable 'book' you return string (`return '<h2>'.$this->model ->text.'</h2>';`). So result in this variable - `$books = $controller ->invoke();` will be string and `$books->name` cause an error

Comment: sorry i didn't understand. when i print_r($book), i got this result    Array ( [PHP for Absolute Beginners] => Book Object ( [name] => PHP for Absolute Beginners [version] => 1.2 [yop] => 1999 ) [Basic Introduction to PHP MVC] => Book Object ( [name] => Basic Introduction to PHP MVC [version] => 1.0 [yop] => 2008 ) [Advanced PHP] => Book Object ( [name] => Advanced PHP [version] => 1.2 [yop] => 2004 ) [Advanced PHP MVC] => Book Object ( [name] => Advanced PHP MVC [version] => 2.0 [yop] => 2014 ) )

Comment: In this case returned an Array, so you must write this: $books['PHP for Absolute Beginners']->name

Comment: Its works partially. thank you. but when i select a different book its shows the same value. can i get the index value of the string within array. like $books[1]->name, instead of $books['PHP for Absolute Beginners'] ->name

Comment: hey @SevStryker thanks for the logic. i got the answer. when i was echoing i access the non-object $book which is an aray. Instead of accessing it i accessed the value that i was sending through GET method.    Here is the modification i did in the echo statement..  echo "You selected ".$books[$_GET['book']]->name   . " version: " . $books[$_GET['book']]->version  . " Year of published: " .  $books[$_GET['book']]->yop ;   now its working fine. Thank you.